# Doing a clone of master, feature branch from that, and during time merging updates from clone branch into feature branch - can i do a rebase?

Tags: git, rebase

I'm quite new to git, and just readupon rebase. Now, will it work for me? The scenario is:

First i did a clone of master branch, lets call it develop.
Then from the local cloned develop i did a clone i.e a featurebranch, lets call it feature.

I then been working on the featurebranch doing local commits, and once in a while switched to cloned develop, did pull, and then back to feature and did a merge from my cloned (and updated) develop.

Now the feature is done, and i want to merge it back to my cloned develop, and after that do a push to remote repo.. but can i first do a rebase to get all  my commits in one place, or am I...smoked?

I guess the correct way would have been to do rebase with every time i wanted to update the feature branch from the cloned develop..right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebase may be appealing because it streamlines the history, but it often makes things simpler than they should be. Rebased commits may be work as you expect them too because the code that you rebased upon changed some assumptions that they were based on, and you won't be able to revert that.

Just merge the feature branch into develop and push it as is. Just don't push local feature branch tag, or delete it if it gets pushed, and in your history it will look like another branch of commits, without littering origin with branch tags.